# MySQL on Mac OS X directories

Tags: mysql, database, macos

For the past week, I was using MySQL just fine. Now today, I go to start the server (it does start) but it says my database cannot be found.

Sure enough, I look in my /usr/local/ directory and find two installations:

`mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86`

`mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64`

It seems as though the `mysql` alias is now pointing towards `mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64`.

I looked in the data directory of that installation and my database is no where to be found. However, I took a look in the other installations data directory and voila it's there.

The weird thing is is that in the `mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86` directory, there is **ONLY** a data directory and nothing else (totally directory size is 70mb). However, the `mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64` directory is a full blown installation at 490 mb.

Is there any reason that my database could be found yesterday in that weird location but not today? I cannot figure out how to get MySQL to find my database, any help, please!

I just don't understand this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use this with mac osx. I recommend you to use 'homebrew' to install all third parts libraries or tools.
Anyway did you have a look to your my.cnf config to see where is located your databases ?
Also you could have a look to the launcher to see which argmuents is used to start your database.